# webpack css-loader colormin/minimize disabling

Tags: css, webpack

There is the following loader:

```
  {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    //loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?-minimize!sass?sourceMap&indentedSyntax')
  }
```

As you can see I want to use css-loader but with minimization disabling. It doesn't work, i.e. I have style:

```
.some-style
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
```

As result:

```
.some-style {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
```

As you can see I have got 'transparent' instead of 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'. How can I disable it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you also using `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` with webpack?

Comment: I have the same exact issue, I am also using ExtractTextPlugin and webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(). how can I go about disabling minify for css but still minify my JS?